# unable to pass array entry as data argument - internal sever error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to invoke c# mvc controller method from custom js script using ajax but it seems it does not accept array entries as argument inside the ajax.

I tried to assign them to a non-array variables and it worked, but I need to pass them as array elements.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> CallEngineAsync(int id, string command)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("/PluginDLLs/");

    string output = await EngineBroker.CallEngine(command, path, AppDomain.CurrentDomain);

   // Session["output"] = output;
   // Session["calledPlugin"] = id;

    var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home");
    return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
}
```

```js
var pluginIDs = [];
var pluginCommands = [];
var pluginIntervals = [];

$(".p-container").find(".p").each(function ()
{
    var confi = $(this).find("#command").attr("value");

    var interval = 1000 * confi.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (confi.includes("interval") && interval > 0)
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-pluginid");
        pluginIDs.push(id);

        pluginCommands.push(confi);

        pluginIntervals.push(interval);
    }
});

for (p = 0; p < pluginIDs.length; p++)
{
    window.setInterval(function (event, ui)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'Home/CallEngineAsync',
            data: { id: pluginIDs[p], command: pluginCommands[p] },
            traditional: true,
            type: 'POST',

            success: function (data)
            {
                window.location.href = data.Url
            },

            error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
        });

    }, pluginIntervals[p]);
}
```

I'm gettint the following error: POST https://localhost:44381/Home/CallEngineAsync 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was some sort of scope problem: variables used inside setInterval() have to be declared in same scope(?) and also the **p**(counter) was always set to final value way due to the timeout, also c# method needed one change in order to properlu fetch arguments:

```cs
public async Task<string> CallEngineAsync([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string command)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("/PluginDLLs/");

            string output = await EngineBroker.CallEngine(command, path, AppDomain.CurrentDomain);

            Session["output" + id] = output;

            return output;
        }
```

```js
$(".p-container").find(".p").each(function ()
{
    var confi = $(this).find("#command").attr("value");

    var interval = 1000 * confi.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (confi.includes("interval") && interval > 0)
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-pluginid");

        var output = $(this).find("#" + id)

        window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'Home/CallEngineAsync',
                data: 'id=' + id + '&command=' + confi,
                traditional: true,
                type: 'GET',

                success: function (data) 
                {
                    output.html('<h4><br />' + data + '</h4>');
                    //window.location.href = data.Url
                },
            });
        }, interval);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to change `POST` to `GET`, and then add this:

```
return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also change:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CallEngineAsync(int id, string command)
```

Comment: still getting: GET https://localhost:44381/Home/CallEngineAsync?id=115 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `localhost:44381/Home/CallEngineAsync?id=115&command=test` is more like your contract, othervise Null reference Exception can occur at `EngineBroker.CallEngine`

Comment: yep, you should add all you params, or predefine them like:
    `public async Task<JsonResult> CallEngineAsync(int id = 0, string command = "test")`

Comment: it does not give that error now but it also does not seem to pass arguments values

Comment: Check this input values, or add test data:
    `data: { id: 1234, command: "test" },`
and then try again.

Comment: it is working as wall as assigning array elements to a different variables

Comment: it seems there is a problem with scope inside js script since i can't use value property for array elements

Comment: seems to me, this is incorrect: `pluginIDs.push[p]`. 
If you want to get value from array, try this:
    `pluginIDs[p]`

Comment: sorry i got a typo, in fact it was pluginIDs[p] all the time